# Documentaiton for Multi / Uni operators

Tags: mutiny

I don't seem to find the documentation for Mutiny that would cover all available operators for Multi / Uni, something similar to [this](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) for example. Is there such a resource? Guides section is great, but I'd like to get a more general idea about library capabilities.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you gave as example is a JavaDoc.

Here's a link to the Mutiny one:
https://javadoc.io/doc/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks! I feel silly now - I was somewhere in the vicinity of that page, but somehow missed it.